# Magento 2 : How to insert Price inclusive Tax?

Tags: magento2

i dont have found the way to insert in magento 2 in create product 
price inclusive Tax .

[image]

in magento 1 was possibile - how i can insert in magento 2

thank you .

Comment: Maybe contact the support. It is no programming related question you're asking.

Comment: @ Michael Czechowski  hello , wich support ? i try to found in the backend but there is nothing , in magento 1 there was possibility to tell magento that if i insert price is already with tax

Comment: You did not get my point. Your question is not about coding the Magento 2 Backend, your question targets the business logic behind it. I recommend to post your question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: ah now i get you .. thank you :-)